# Selenium c# scraping information from a webpage

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to run the code from the selenium documentation in this website, https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/. The only change I have made is that I am using a chrome driver instead of a firefox driver. The error that I am getting is `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"h3>div"}`. I assume this means that the h3>div element can't be found and the only reason that I can think of is that I need to accept the cookies before I can locate the element.

I have tried to print out the page source and locate the h3 or div tags but the page source is too big to fit in my terminal.

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/ncr");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("cheese" + Keys.Enter);
            wait.Until(webDriver => webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("h3>div")).Displayed);
            IWebElement firstResult = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("h3>div"));
            Console.WriteLine(firstResult.GetAttribute("textContent"));
        }
```

The line where the code crashes is the 6th line beginning wait.Until with the error message shown above.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a representative example of the HTML. Please also include frames or iframes if the target element exists inside them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the locator `h3>div` no longer exists on the search results page. That code is probably old and google.com is probably not the best site as a code example because they redesign often. You can replace it with `h3` and the code should work.

---

Since you are new, let me make a couple suggestions.

1. Test your locators in the browser. You can do this in the Chrome dev console. You can use `$$()` for CSS selectors and `$x()` for XPaths. In your case, you would type `$$("h3>div")` into the console and see that it returns 0 elements. Now try `$$("h3")` and see that it returns 20 elements. Read more about the [Chrome dev console](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/).
2. That code isn't really demonstrating best practices... it has some but falls short on others. If I were to write it, it would look like

   ```
    using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
    {
        driver.Url = "https://www.google.com/ncr";
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("cheese" + Keys.Enter);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        IWebElement firstResult = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("h3")));
        Console.WriteLine(firstResult.Text);
    }
   ```

   Here's what I changed:

   1. The `WebDriverWait` should be defined where you use it, not at the top of the script.
   2. Use `ExpectedConditions` so you don't have to write your own custom waits for common things. See [the docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) for more info.
   3. `.ElementIsVisible()` returns the element waited for so you don't have to wait (hitting the page), then scrape the page (hitting the page again), then print the text.
   4. Use `.Text` instead of `.GetAttribute("textContent")`. `.Text` does (basically) the same thing and works in all cases I've run into. If you typo the spelling or capitalization of "textContent", you won't find out until you run the test, etc. It's just faster, better, easier to use `.Text` until you run into a rare situation where it doesn't work.